# performance.now() returns different values when we change the order of execution

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing, performance.now

I was just trying to see the performance difference in using `||` (double pipes, short-circuit operator, which should be faster) instead of `|`.

But the result gave no insight to the actual performance improvements. If we just reorder the below codes..to execute console log with `|` first, then it will show more time than the other.

1. How can I see the performance difference using this or any other way? Also,
2. Can somebody explain why there is difference when we change the order?

   If `performance.now();` behaves like this, I don't see any point in using it.

Please help. Thanks :)

```js
var t3 = performance.now();
console.log(1 | (1),
  1 || (0),
  1 || (-1),
  1 || ("a string"),
  1 || (""),
  1 || (null),
  1 || (undefined),
  1 || (console.log(3)),
  1 || (Infinity))
var t4 = performance.now();
console.log("Call with (double) '||' took " + (t4 - t3) + " milliseconds.");

var t0 = performance.now();
console.log(1 | (1),
  1 | (0),
  1 | (-1),
  1 | ("a string"),
  1 | (""),
  1 | (null),
  1 | (undefined),
  1 | (console.log(3)),
  1 | (Infinity))
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call with single | took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

Comment: @Siguza that doesnt explain my question.

Comment: (My bad, the dupe I picked sucks in regard to serious performance testing.) As with any and all performance tests, you should 1) execute the tests at least a couple of thousand times (if not millions), 2) warm up the environment, i.e. do a couple of thousand of the operations you want to test _before_ starting to measure the time, and 3) make sure you move input/output functions (i.e. all `console.log`) out of the measured block unless you actually want to measure _them_. Unrelated to that, why do you want to compare `|` to `||`? They don't do the same thing.

Comment: `|` and `||` do almost same. But `||` wont check for the right side expressions if left is true. So there should be performance improvement

Comment: I've just created a jsperf test, you can run it [here](https://jsperf.com/singlevsdoublepipe/1)

Comment: @baao Thanks. But still why there is a change in values when we change the order?

Comment: @Mendax Because left becomes right.

Comment: @changed Not _that_ order. One test before the other.

Comment: @Siguza I suppose you answered that with your comment.

Comment: @Mendax Because your performance test is bad. `console.log` could easily take 100 times as long as all your calculations, and calling it for the first time might trigger initialization that takes again 100 times as long as the second time you call it. That's what I meant with "warm up the environment". And again, **one invocation is not representative**. You should collect many (thousands, millions) of samples and then look at the average. Anything else is random and unreliable.

Comment: @Siguza thanks. Like you said I tried adding a console log before measuring..then the values are almost close... So that means we need to train the engine before using `performance` API?.

Comment: also be aware that `|` (Bitwise OR) and `||` (Logical OR) don't do the same. `|` converts both operands to a signed 32 Bit Integer, bitwise ORs them and returns the result. `||` checks if the left operand is truthy, if it is, it returns the value of the left operand, if it isn't it returns the value of the right operand. If evaluated in a boolean context (for example `if(a | b)` compared to `if(a || b)` they may lead to different results. Compare `if("string"|0)` to `if("string" || 0)`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How can I see the performance difference using this or any other way?
> 2. Can somebody explain why there is difference when we change the order?

1. Do many tests. Single tests (especially ones that take little time) have an extreme risk of being interfered with by your browser or your OS, which can at any point decide to pause execution, do something else, and come back later.
2. Warm up the environment. Almost everything that does input/output (such as `console.log`) need initialisation, which will be done the first time it is used, which can easily disrupt the measured performance by several orders of magnitude.
3. Strip away everything that does not strictly belong to your test. If you want to compare `|` vs `||`, then don't include `console.log` in the block that is being timed.

Some demonstrations:

Run the following code a couple of times. Observe that:

1. Often (but not always) the first one takes longer. That's initialisation.
2. Sometimes one takes multiple times as long as the other. That's interference.

```js
var t3 = performance.now();
console.log("herp");
var t4 = performance.now();

var t0 = performance.now();
console.log("derp");
var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Call with herp took " + (t4 - t3) + " milliseconds.");
console.log("Call with derp took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

Also observe that I/O has a horrendous effect on performance: (you'll need to scroll down)

```js
var discard = function(){}; // just discards everything

var t3 = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    discard("");
}
var t4 = performance.now();

var t0 = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    console.log("");
}
var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("discard() took " + (t4 - t3) + " milliseconds.");
console.log("console.log() took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

Taking all that into account, let's write a test case that tests your operations:

```js
var discard = function(){};

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    discard(1 | (1),
      1 || (0),
      1 || (-1),
      1 || ("a string"),
      1 || (""),
      1 || (null),
      1 || (undefined),
      1 || (console.log(3)),
      1 || (Infinity));
}
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    discard(1 | (1),
      1 | (0),
      1 | (-1),
      1 | ("a string"),
      1 | (""),
      1 | (null),
      1 | (undefined),
      1 | (console.log(3)),
      1 | (Infinity));
}

var t3 = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    discard(1 | (1),
      1 || (0),
      1 || (-1),
      1 || ("a string"),
      1 || (""),
      1 || (null),
      1 || (undefined),
      1 || (console.log(3)),
      1 || (Infinity));
}
var t4 = performance.now();

var t0 = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    discard(1 | (1),
      1 | (0),
      1 | (-1),
      1 | ("a string"),
      1 | (""),
      1 | (null),
      1 | (undefined),
      1 | (console.log(3)),
      1 | (Infinity));
}
var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Call with (double) '||' took " + (t4 - t3) + " milliseconds.");
console.log("Call with single | took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

Note that pretty much all of the time it takes the `|` case to complete is still coming from `console.log`, proving only that short-circuiting on `||` truly works. Now of course this is accurate for `|` vs `||` operations that actually involve I/O. If you leave that out however, the results are much close together again:

(Note that I cranked up the for loop to 10 million, proving just **how much time** `console.log` actually takes!)

```js
var discard = function(){};

for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    discard(1 | (1),
      1 || (0),
      1 || (-1),
      1 || ("a string"),
      1 || (""),
      1 || (null),
      1 || (undefined),
      1 || (Infinity));
}
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    discard(1 | (1),
      1 | (0),
      1 | (-1),
      1 | ("a string"),
      1 | (""),
      1 | (null),
      1 | (undefined),
      1 | (Infinity));
}

var t3 = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    discard(1 | (1),
      1 || (0),
      1 || (-1),
      1 || ("a string"),
      1 || (""),
      1 || (null),
      1 || (undefined),
      1 || (Infinity));
}
var t4 = performance.now();

var t0 = performance.now();
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    discard(1 | (1),
      1 | (0),
      1 | (-1),
      1 | ("a string"),
      1 | (""),
      1 | (null),
      1 | (undefined),
      1 | (Infinity));
}
var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Call with (double) '||' took " + (t4 - t3) + " milliseconds.");
console.log("Call with single | took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

And in spite of all of that, `|` and `||` do entirely different things. Not only in terms of execution, but also in terms of the result. Try `1 || 126` vs `1 | 126`, or `"a" || "b"` vs `"a" | "b"`.